# Zip file cracker python 3 - Proof of concept

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, brute-force

How would i expand upon my existing function in order to get it to try the password on a locked zip file

```
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
password = "hello"

def brute_force(x, y):    
#Where x stands for chars(list to check in) and y stands for password variable to check against
    for length in range(1, 100):    
        to_attempt = product(x, repeat=length)
        for attempt in to_attempt:
            i = i + 1
            if ''.join(attempt) == y:
                print('Password: ' + ''.join(attempt))
                return
```

Comment: what is product function doing??

Comment: im sure its the itertools.product method (generator for all permutations of set x of size repreat)

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: How is this one wrong? you cant really break a password other than with brute force (or finding exploits in the encryption/security).  how would you suggest "expanding" on this? what do you even mean by that?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I think he's referring to the fact that he has his algorithm to brute-force, but he wants to know how he could test each password against the zip file.

Comment: @AlexThornton YES that is exactly what i want

Comment: @MatthewStevens-Keane There you go, happy to help- see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't completely re-write your function for you, but to test each `attempt` you would do (`import zipfile` at the top):

```
f = zipfile.ZipFile('path/to/file')
for attempt in attempts:
    try:
        f.extractall(pwd=attempt)
    except RuntimeError:
        continue
    else:
        return attempt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def brute_force(x, y): 
    #since you already have the password just return it
    return y
```

ok ok that probably wasnt the answer you are looking for ...

but really the only way I know of(assuming you dont know an exploit to decode whatever encryption this might be) is to brute force it...

of coarse many systems have vunerabilities you can exploit to gain access without necessarilly "guessing " the password

if you are asking how can you not include y and instead test it against a real file try the [zipfile module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html) , which includes a password option for most methods

Answer (score 0):

using `zipfile` module

```
import zipfile
z = zipfile.Zipfile('your_zip_file')
def searching(z,x):
try:
    z.extractall(pwd=x)
    print "\n[+]Password found: " + x 
    exit
except:
    pass

# loop over you combination call searching
   searching(z,pwd)
```

This might will help you. you can use concept of threading to make it faster